# How to crop image in opencv with android

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

i Have a rectangle drawn by opencv+java+android. now i need to crop and display in my imagviwe how to crop it. submat methord is allow only int values. but rect.tl().x values are in double. casting is not a good solution. it make errors.

`Core.rectangle(ImageMatin, rect.tl(), rect.br(), new Scalar(255, 0, 0),1); // works
Mat cropped = ImageMatin.submat(rect.tl().x, rect.height, rect.tl().x, rect.width); //error`

Comment: I think u can try cropimage library .https://github.com/biokys/cropimage

Answer (score 0):

i recommend this library from github: https://github.com/edmodo/cropper , it even has a sample so if you get stuck you can always refer to it. Also this library is great for cropping purposes and lightweight as well, i myself have used it in one or two apps

Answer (score 0):

You can crop Mat images by appling this command:

```
Mat croppedImg = new Mat (sourceMat, ROI);
```